# Issues and benefits related to having the ability to see and have an affinity for portals?

Tags: transportation, dimensions, abilities, evil

I am writing a story in which people with a rare genetic ability are able to see, and are attracted to portals which lead to other dimensions.

I have some ideas on how I want to differentiate good vs evil in this book, but I am interested in some more ideas.

```
                                                   My Idea
```

"Arcs" are portals (which are shaped like arcs) which are used to travel to other dimensions that are identical in form to our universe, but "life" in not identical (referring to people culture, society, happenings within the universe)

THE ARCANE are people with the ability of "Allsight," meaning they have the ability to see and sense portals to other dimensions. They have been guardians of the dimensions and have protected arc-blind people from accidents and tragedies that can come from traveling through arcs.

However, some of the Arcane began to become corrupt and greedy. They wanted to use their ability to the advantage of themselves and gain more power. These ones, so far, I am calling "Archangels"

So, how could this ability be useful and how could one who possesses that ability use it for evil? Hopefully that makes sense. Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: You said the Arcane use the power to protect others, so the act of not protecting or telling them is potentially evil without actually doing any new evil acts.

Comment: I suppose it would be. It's sort of like be a bystander to an act of bullying. You're not doing it, but you're also not preventing it either. Thank you.

Comment: The [help/dont-ask] states, "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers."  That same page also says questions shouldn't be asked where "every answer is equally valid." VTC:Needs Details until you provide a clear explanation for how you'll judge the best answer. Remember, SE is not a discussion forum. One-specific-question/one-best-answer.

Answer (score 4):

**By being an arms merchant**

In any war between two sides, the one who always profits are the people selling weapons. (Assuming, of course, that the ones producing the weapons are independent of the ones fighting.) And, if you can be the person selling weapons to *both* sides - well, that's mountains of profits for as long as the war goes on, and you have all the incentive in the world to keep this ongoing. This is why no one likes war profiteers.

Someone who is evil and has access to portals just because the world's ultimate black market weapons dealer. Let's say one of these portals leads to a world with technology 150 years ago? Well, just travel there and sell some modern arms in exchange for rare metals - gold, platinum, etc. One of these portal leads to somewhere technologically ahead of us? Go there, spend some of those rare metals, and come back to Earth selling your futuristic arms to the highest bidder. Not to mention that traveling via portal has the potential to let you get around restrictions and blockades with ease, so your smuggling will be very hard to stop.

Sure, you'll cause untold havoc and destruction by giving horrifyingly powerful weapons to people who really shouldn't have them and possibly lead to the death and exploitation of entire worlds, but at the end of the day, you'll be filthy rich. So you have to ask yourself: "If I was extraordinarily evil, would I care about crushing the lives of millions just so I could be fabulously wealthy?" (Hopefully, the answer is still no, because that's an awfully large cost. But that's pretty much one of the worse things I think you can do with this.)

Comment: It’s not profiting off death. It’s selling Freedom!!

Answer (score 1):

### Sell the access

1. Allow criminals to escape the police.  Other possibilities are debtors, or other people with reason to flee.  (The last can be ambiguous, morally, or turn on the extortionate price).  This can be temporary or permanent.
2. Enable smuggling.  This might be from dimension to dimension.  Only if the portals are situated right can you smuggle from one region in your own dimension to another.  (Evil can be variable depending on the reason for the smuggling.)
3. Enable resource extraction.  This world never discovered that there were emeralds here?  We'll just mine them and bring them back to our own world.

Answer (score 1):

**GET RID OF PEOPLE**

When criminals or corrupt politicians or corporations want to 'vanish' people, what better way than having them removed to another dimension? They will literally be gone without a trace. It wouldn't be anywhere as near as bad as murder, since the victim would be able to survive (and possibly even thrive) on the other side of the portal. This would also make it a moral grey zone that the 'archangels' may find acceptable.

This, of course, depends on how common the portals are. You wouldn't want to carry abducted victims across half a continent to get to a portal you can chuck them through.

**SELL STORIES AND MUSIC**

Books, plays, and myths from one world can be sold in another world as fantasy or science fiction. An archangel could set himself up as a very prolific writer doing stories set in a rich and coherent 'invented' world, or as a composer writing music and songs that are literally "out of this world". Again, this is a moral grey zone - you could even argue that it counts as doing good - and an archangel could make good money with very little work involved (mainly translation).

**WASTE DISPOSAL**

Offer to remove waste at low prices - even toxic or radioactive waste. Dump it through a portal to an uninhabited world or a remote area of a thinly populated world. Who knows, if you dump biological waste on a dead planet, you might even kickstart life there. Not really evil, though other Arcanes might frown on it.

Answer (score 0):

**Price arbitrage**

Find pairs of commodities that have different price ratios in the various worlds, then trade them. This might be considered good or evil, but it's certainly greed, or it can be used to finance evil acts elsewhere.

Comment: The entirety of the modern financial world is built on the assumption that this is a good thing. We’ve even gone far enough to start trading entirely abstract concepts like ‘shares’ and ‘futures’. Just imagine the joy of the financial analysts if they learnt there was an entire multiverse of financial markets to trade against!

Comment: Indeed. Works just as well with gems or precious metals, though, for a more medieval feel.

Answer (score 0):

In your story there're a lot of possible evil person that have this ability.

1. The Merchant, he can trade or steal technology and resource in a dimension with low defense for selling in his dimension to a Criminal Organization or other person.
2. The Assassin, is mind is corrupted and kill persons in any dimension for money or other stuff.
3. The Leader of Crime Organization, he gain so much money during the dimensional change that create a crime organization with creature (if it possible tranport creature through the "Arcs") of another dimension. The ultimate goal of this Corrupted Arcane is a dictator of state or whole World.
4. The Mad, travelling in a foolish dimension he's got insane when encounter a strange creature or other like that, so he can choose to find a way to open a portal much bigger that can transport the strange creature.
5. The Enslaver, travelling dimension selling creature for his personal power or working for someone.

These are only 5 type, but i think the ability to see a dimensional passage and the possibility to travel to another dimension is a interesting plot for a story, there are different ways that a person with that gift can do for good or evil.
Perhaps the Good Arcane can develope an Organization that fight the "Archangels", i think that using the term "Archangels" is too much linked with religion.

You can use a scenario for a Dimensional War.